# Using ECMA6 Set as object key

Tags: javascript, set

Is there a way to use `Set` as object keys

```js
let x = {}

const a = new Set([3, 5])

x[a] = 1

console.log(x) // >{[object Set]: 1}

const b = new Set([1, 4])

x[b] = 2

console.log(x) // >{[object Set]: 2}
```

The keys are being overwritten even though the sets are not equal.

Thanks!

Comment: No, object keys are only strings or symbols. Anything that's neither is converted to a string. You can use a map that preserves the key types, however two sets are considered different even if they contain the same values.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No this is not possible because Object keys must be strings or symbols. If you would like to use a Set as a key you can try using a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). Maps are similar to objects except you can use other objects as keys for a map.

One thing to keep in mind is that you cannot use maps exactly like you use Objects.

This is directly from the Mozilla docs.
The following **IS NOT A VALID USE OF A MAP**.

```js
let wrongMap = new Map()
wrongMap['bla'] = 'blaa'
wrongMap['bla2'] = 'blaaa2'

console.log(wrongMap)  // Map { bla: 'blaa', bla2: 'blaaa2' }
```

> But that way of setting a property does not interact with the Map data structure. It uses the feature of the generic object. The value of 'bla' is not stored in the Map for queries. Other operations on the data fail:

Correct use of a map looks like the below:

```js
let map = new Map()

// setting values
map.set(key, value)

// getting values
map.get(key)
```

Remember that if you use an Object like a Set as a key, the reference of the Set is what matters.

If you instantiate two sets separately, even if they both have the same contents, they will have different references and be considered different keys.

Comment: yeah well, thanks, but is there any way two sets with the same members will be considered same key?

Comment: @Moses The first thing that comes to mind would be to stringify the set and use the string as the key but you need to make sure the order is consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that the `map` in `ES6` like this:

```js
x = new Map()

a = new Set([3, 5])

x.set(a, 1)

console.log(x);
```